# Is this the correct way of building a voltage divider through this Link

Tags: resistors, adc, voltage-divider, infrared, breadboard

I’m trying to build a voltage divider through following the instructions on this link http://raspberry.io/projects/view/reading-from-a-mcp3002-analog-to-digital-converter/#step1  I have connected the ADC (analog to digital converter) and the resistor to the breadboard and I was supposed to substitute the potentiometer in the example for the Infrared distance Sensor so according to the diagrams on this link is this the correct way of building a voltage divider on this image shown here

[image]

Comment: Without any more information as to the infrared distance sensor, it's impossible to answer this question. It's also very likely you don't want to connect it in this manner - the voltage devider in the example was only there to provide an input for the sake of the project.

Comment: Your photo shows a breadboard with three components plugged in but nothing connected to anything else!

Comment: IR distance sensor produces an output in voltage not resistance. So there is no point interfacing it in voltage divider connection. You can directly interface the IR distance sensor to an ADC and interpret the values according to your programming requirements.

Comment: I was suppose to connect this breadboard circuit to the raspberry pi

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering.  Be sure to take the tour (and earn a badge) at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: Please go back and edit your question right away and tell us what kind of IR sensor you have.    It will be easier to attract good answers that way.

Answer (score 0):

The sharp GP2Yxxxxx sensors (which I'm guessing is what you have, clarification would be appreciated) output an analog voltage all by themselves, they do not need another external resistor. Simply connect the output of the sensor directly to your ADC; you do not need a voltage divider.

Comment: So what Your saying is do I only connect the Infrared distance sensor and ADC on the breadboard

Comment: how do I connect the output of the sensor directly to the ADC on the breadboard could you give me an example?

Comment: The output of the IR sensor can be connected directly to the input of the ADC. I can't get much more explicit than that.

Answer (score 0):

No.   Your breadboard is not set up as per that link in the OP.

Here is the correct way to wire it:
[image]

Comment: Thankyou very much, Yeah I knew this would be it I just need an Pi cobbler and Male to Male jumper wire cables in order to finish  building the voltage divider

Comment: Yep.  Then when you have it wired up (and hopefully working) you can come back and edit your question again with a photo showing how you did it.